# Why Chrome devtools console log automatic

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, console.log, devtools

When i using devtools in chrome the devtools console log things by him self, The devtools console.log exactly what i have on Local storage.

every single time when i open the devtools it is display automatically, I would love to disable this issue, I add image to clarify my problem.

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8rBK.png

it was checked on all folder and file in my project and there is nothing about it.
as you can see it's came from contentscript.js.

Comment: DevTools should not log those lines automatically. If you click on the grey "contentscript.js:8" at the top right of the logged message, it should take you to where the message is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I think `contentscript.js` is part of the Chrome extensions library which gets loaded everytime an extension loads. Most likely you have an extension installed that is logging those statements.

Try disabling extensions one at a time, to find the extension causing those log statements.

[image]